# Windows Do not Disturb isnt setting Notification state

Tags: c++, windows, notifications, windows-11

Previous similiar answers are no longer supported or were never supported is there no way supported though Microsoft to query this mode? Something like Notification state?

I am creating an app that will send notifications to the user on a Windows machine. I am currently checking the [Notification state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ne-shellapi-query_user_notification_state) to know if I can show my pop up.

That works if the user is in presentation mode, or presenting in a Teams call, but if they set Do Not Disturb mode in Windows, it still returns Accepts notifications.

I have not been able to find a way to query Do Not Disturb. Does anyone know how I can check that?

Here is my current code:

```cpp
bool CheckNotificationState()
{
    QUERY_USER_NOTIFICATION_STATE notificationState = 
    QUNS_ACCEPTS_NOTIFICATIONS;
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    if (g_bCheckNotificationState){
        LogInfo("Checking Notification State");
        hr = SHQueryUserNotificationState(&notificationState);
        if (hr != S_OK || notificationState != QUNS_ACCEPTS_NOTIFICATIONS)
        {
               LogInfo("User not accepting notifications");
               return false;
        }
    }    
    return true;
}
```

Here is a snippet to do it in Powershell:

```
$winClass = Add-Type -MemberDefinition '     [DllImport("shell32.dll")]     public static extern int SHQueryUserNotificationState(out int state); ' -Name WinClass -PassThru
$state = [int]0 
$null = $WinClass::SHQueryUserNotificationState([ref]$state) 
write-host "state: $state"
```

Comment: What about QUNS_BUSY?

Comment: It returns Accepts notifications in Do not disturb mode